# How to scale tiled bitmaps with glDrawTexfoes?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a game that is using glDrawTexfoes() exclusively for graphics. It is 2d of course. Up until now, I did not stretch the graphics when drawing them: I had 2 sets, one small one large for different devices. That approach has reach it limit (and frankly I shouldn't ever have used it - but that was 2 years ago).

So now I am trying to use a single set of images and using glDrawTexfoes, to scale them to fill up the display. It is working for the most part except where I tile images. I've included an image showing the result. The vertical lines are not supposed to be there.

[image: button problem]

I have played with the texture parameters as much as I could, but I can't get rid of this problem, so I am turning to SO. Here are some details: the image is NOT power of 2. It is not using sprite sheet, each sprite has its own bitmap.

I create the texture using this code

```
    bitmap.prepareTexture(_glMaxTextureSize);

    gl.glGenTextures(1, mTextureNameWorkspace, 0);

    int error = gl.glGetError();
    if (error != GL10.GL_NO_ERROR) {
        Log.d("Texture Load 1", "GLError: " + error + " (" + GLU.gluErrorString(error) + "): " + bitmap.toString() );
    }

    assert error == GL10.GL_NO_ERROR;

    bitmap.textureName = mTextureNameWorkspace[0];

    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, bitmap.textureName);

    error = gl.glGetError();
    if (error != GL10.GL_NO_ERROR) {
        Log.d("Texture Load 2", "GLError: " + error + " (" + GLU.gluErrorString(error) + "): " + bitmap.toString());
    }

    assert error == GL10.GL_NO_ERROR;

    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);

    gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL10.GL_REPLACE); //GL10.GL_REPLACE);

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap.textureHanlde, 0);

    error = gl.glGetError();
    if (error != GL10.GL_NO_ERROR) {
        Log.d("Texture Load 3", "GLError: " + error + " (" + GLU.gluErrorString(error) + "): " + bitmap.toString());
    }

    bitmap.releaseTextureBitmap();

    assert error == GL10.GL_NO_ERROR;

    mCropWorkspace[0] = 0;
    mCropWorkspace[1] = bitmap.getHeight();
    mCropWorkspace[2] = bitmap.getWidth();
    mCropWorkspace[3] = -bitmap.getHeight();

    ((GL11) gl).glTexParameteriv(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES, mCropWorkspace, 0);

    error = gl.glGetError();
    if (error != GL10.GL_NO_ERROR) {
        Log.d("Texture Load 4", "GLError: " + error + " (" + GLU.gluErrorString(error) + "): " + bitmap.toString());
    }

    assert error == GL10.GL_NO_ERROR;
```

The opengl context is created with the following code

```
       /*
    * Some one-time OpenGL initialization can be made here probably based
    * on features of this particular context
    */
   gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);

   gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1);
   gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_FLAT);
   gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
   /*
    * By default, OpenGL enables features that improve quality but reduce
    * performance. One might want to tweak that especially on software
    * renderer.
    */
   gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
   gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);

   gl.glTexEnvx(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL10.GL_MODULATE);

   gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

The viewport is set in the following fashion

```
      float scaleX = (float)w / _screenWidth;
  float scaleY =  (float)h / _screenHeight;
  final int viewportWidth = (int)(_screenWidth * scaleX);
  final int viewportHeight = (int)(_screenHeight * scaleY);
  gl.glViewport(0, 0, viewportWidth, viewportHeight);
  mScaleX = scaleX;
  mScaleY = scaleY;

  /*
   * Set our projection matrix. This doesn't have to be done each time we
   * draw, but usually a new projection needs to be set when the viewport
   * is resized.
   */
  float ratio = (float) _screenWidth / _screenHeight;
  gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
  gl.glLoadIdentity();
  gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 10);
```

Finally, and excuse the wall of code, the drawing is done with

```
 gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_FLAT);
   gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
   gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
   gl.glColor4x(0x10000, 0x10000, 0x10000, 0x10000);

   gl.glViewport(0, 0, (int)viewWidth, (int)viewHeight);
   gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
   gl.glLoadIdentity();
   gl.glOrthof(0, viewWidth, viewHeight, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
   gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
   gl.glLoadIdentity();

   gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

   [loop over sprites]
           final float screenScale = 800/600f; // hardcoded to test stuff out
           final float snappedX = ((x  + transX)*screenScale); //+ e.speedX * interpolation;
           final float snappedY = _screenHeight - (y + height + transY ) * screenScale;//+ e.speedY * interpolation);
           final int texName = ob.textureName;

           gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName);

           _cropWorkspace[0] = left;
           _cropWorkspace[1] = top + height;
           _cropWorkspace[2] = width;
           _cropWorkspace[3] = -height;

           if( operation == Drawer.MIRROR_X )
           {
              _cropWorkspace[0] = left + width;
              _cropWorkspace[2] = -width;
           }

           ((GL11) gl).glTexParameteriv(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES, _cropWorkspace, 0);
           ((GL11Ext) gl).glDrawTexfOES(snappedX, snappedY, 1, width * screenScale, height * screenScale );
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem: due to the scaling and the oversampling, I needed to add a border/padding around the crop space of the bitmap to avoid the black lines.

```
_cropWorkspace[0] = left + padding;
_cropWorkspace[1] = top + height - padding;
_cropWorkspace[2] = width - padding * 2;
_cropWorkspace[3] = -(height-padding*2);
```